# convert string column values to array-like values in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table named `test` with two columns named `title` and `tags`.

Suppose we have some values like this in some rows in the title column:

```
"a2644 dual sim 128gb 6gb not activated"
```

now I want to convert it to an array-like string and save it in `tags` columns. like this :

```
[ "a2644" , "dual sim" , "128gb" , "6gb" , "not activated" ]
```

Note that we have many rows like the above Example the `tags` column is empty now.

I need a query that can read the title column of each row and then convert it to the desired array and update `tags` column.

Comment: I do not think that is even possible since you need words such as `dual sim` or `not activated`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do it like this

**For PostgreSQL**

UPDATE test
SET tags = STRING_TO_ARRAY(tags, ' ')
WHERE tags IS NOT NULL;

**For MySQL**

Here you will have to use your programming skills to make this dynamic.

UPDATE test
SET tags = CONCAT('[ "',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, ',', 1),
'" , "',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, ',', 2), ',', -1),
'" , "',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, ',', 3), ',', -1),
'" , "',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, ',', 4), ',', -1),
'" , "',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, ',', 5), ',', -1),
'" ]')
WHERE tags IS NOT NULL;

Comment: Can you please post the link of  the MySQL documentation where  STRING_TO_ARRAY function is explained ?

Comment: Even in [PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/j2ExhV0n) it gives not the expected result

Comment: I checked in PostgreSQL. It works fine for Version 13 and above. Didn't check with lower versions.

Comment: @Ergest Basha I tried it in MySQL 8.0.33, and got `ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION string_to_array does not exist`. Besides, searching for it on the internet has yielded no result .

Comment: @blabla_bingo It doesn't exist in MySQL, that was for the answerer that `MySQL` <> `PostgreSQL`

Comment: I have updated my answer for MySQL as well.

Comment: @NikhilG  it doesn't work in PostgreSQL as I already posted the link in my second comment,  and it doesn't work in MySQL https://dbfiddle.uk/A3rH0Qhg . Please test your answer before posting and add some explanation

Comment: @ErgestBasha I always do my homework. Check this out https://dbfiddle.uk/GKXxMfF_

Comment: @ErgestBasha Here you can check for Postgres. https://dbfiddle.uk/nHVUyT7k

Comment: @blabla_bingo You too can check.

Comment: @NikhilG it seems that you don't. It's not the problem in the single words separated by spaces but in the words such as `dual sim` or `not activated` which the OP needs combined

Comment: ohh yes. I didn't checked that. But then why he accepted the answer.

Comment: @NikhilG eh that is a question to ask to the OP.